# I can't figure out how to make iMacros write here

Tags: macros, blogs, tumblr, imacros

I am making an iMacros script to take images from my site and post them on my Tumblr blog. How do I make it write here? 
[image]

I have tried all the highlighted tags and just can't make it work.

Cheers

Comment: For this use EVENT and you have to click on this section and start typing. Then use JavaScript scripting to insert the link. Here is a example of JS code. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354868/imacros-invitation-code-missing-3-letters-numbers/25368512#25368512